# Restrict access to Powermail upload folder

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, powermail

Uploaded files in a powermail form are stored in 
http://www.domain.com/uploads/tx_powermail/
Anybody has access to these files!
Is there a way to restrict the access to the uploaded files?
When i add a .htaccess file in the folder with 
`Deny from all`
Will Powermail and TYPO3 still have enough permissions to save and read the uploaded files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a .htaccess file in the folder with "deny from all" will restrict the access to the files.
Maybe could the powermail extension automaticly add the htacces file on installation.

Comment: This is for Apache Web server only. Also, it is for Apache < 2.4 (while this will still work with 2.4 if compatibility module is used). See official docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time

Comment: **If** it is not necessary for the files to be in the web directory, perhaps it is possible to change the directory path?

Comment: see also issue: https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/issues/427

Answer (score 0):

First you should check your domain don't have security token like htaccess password authentication if not, so you can give this folder permission to 02755 it can help, or in the end you can change the path of the folder by typoscript.